# Instantiate C++ template class without parameter / depending on type in if-statement

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I wrote different function objects A, B, and C in C++ and I want to instantiate a template class with one of the function objects, depending on the user input. But as it seems there is no way to instantiate only one of the types in an if statement, is it?

If I try to instantiate one class with a template in the if statement, the g++ compiler gives me a "use of undeclared identifier 'bkt'"-error. If I instantiate it beforehand, the class destroys itself when leaving the if-statement.

Here's my code:

```
class A {
public: void operator()(int a) {}
}; 

class B {
public: void operator()(int a) {}
}; 

class C {
public: void operator()(int a) {}
}; 

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass<T>(const std::string &file);
  ~MyClass<T>;

private:
  T m_func;

int doStuff(int a) {
  return m_func(a);
 }
};

int main() {

std::string filename = std::string(argv[1]);
std::getline(std::cin, metric);

if (metric == "A") {
  MyClass<A> foo(filename);
}
else if (metric == "B") {
  MyClass<B> foo(filename);
}
else {
  MyClass<C> foo(filename);
}

int a = 1;
foo.doStuff(int a); // undeclared identifier "foo"

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I know, that I somehow have to declare the foo-variable, but I was hoping the compiler might be ok with it because one of the cases of the if-statement will happen anyways. Obviously it's not, so what can I do in order to not instantiate every single type?

Comment: does it really have to be a template parameter? Your different metric seem to be all of same type, is this just due to simplification of the example? If not I'd suggest to drop the template. Choosing a tempalte instantiation at runtime isnt really where tempaltes shine. Templates have to be instantiated at compile time

Comment: sorry for being sloppy, they are of course not of same type, but simple refactoring can make them so, while staying with the tempalte requires more effort

Comment: You can declare `int a = 1;` before the metric evaluation and then call `foo.doStuff(a);` inside each `if` statements (I know it's code repetition, but without refactoring, I can't see another way through). **Note**: You have to give `a` and not `int a` in the `foo.doStuff()` call.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 using templates is part of the requirements. Annnd yes the functions actually do very different things (it's the declaration which string metric (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) to use for autocorrection)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms: Templates help you with compile-time polymorphism but what you want is runtime-polymorphism. However, it is straightforward to mix them.

First you create a base class:

```
struct MyBase {
    ~MyBase(){}
    virtual int doStuff(int a) = 0;
};
```

Then you let the templated class inherit from it:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass : MyBase {
public:
   MyClass<T>(const std::string &file);
   ~MyClass<T>;    
private:
   T m_func;
int doStuff(int a) override {
  return m_func(a);
 }
};
```

Now you can have a pointer to `MyBase` and inside the if-cases assign the concrete type. I hope you get the idea and will only give a rough sketch:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyBase> foo;              // or perhaps a unique_ptr
if (metric == "A") {
    foo = ... create MyClass<A>
} else if (metric == "B") {
    ...
}
foo->doStuff(3);
```

For the sake of completeness...your code didnt work, because in

```
if (metric == "A") {
  MyClass<A> foo(filename);
}
```

the lifetime of `foo` is limited to the scope of the `if` case which ends with `}` and you cannot access it outside.

**PS**: as all of the metrics have the same signature, I would have used a different approach that does not require `MyClass` to be a template. Anyhow, `MyClass` being a template seems to be a requirement.

**PPS**: Maybe it is just a matter of wording, but...

> so what can I do in order to not instantiate every single type?

You can't do anything about that. Templates are instantiated at compile time. If you want to pick one instantiation at runtime you need to have them instantiated. In the above code (once you fill the holes) there will be an instantiation for each possible metric, but it is only one instance that gets created.

Comment: Nice thanks. I think, I'm almost there, but it still gives me the "no viable overloaded '=' "-error:

Comment: saying: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'MyClass<A> *' to 'const std::__1::shared_ptr<MyBase>' for
      1st argument

Comment: Can I cast the pointers in a way or it the only way to solve this problem to overload the = operator?

Comment: @NinellOldenburg I will edit it to a more complete example later...

Comment: Thanks! I added some things, castet the pointer and it worked very fine! Now the fault lies somewhere in the override, idk what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @NinellOldenburg sry didnt have time to make the example complete, but it is still on my list. I will ping you once I find time to edit